# How can I find all DbSets whose generic types derive from a given base type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection, entity-framework-4.1

How can I get a `List` of all DbSets where the contained type derives from `IncomingServiceOrderBase`?

I can use reflection to get the all the DbSets, but how do I filter it down to just those that contain a derived type?

**Context**

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BuildingOrder> BuildingOrders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DeliveryOrder> DeliveryOrders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RetailAssemblyOrder> RetailAssemblyOrders { get; set; }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class BuildingOrder : IncomingManufacturedProductOrderBase { }
public class DeliveryOrder : IncomingServiceOrderBase { }
public class RetailAssemblyOrder : IncomingServiceOrderBase { }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do somehing like this:

```
var sets =
    from p in typeof(MyContext).GetProperties()
    where p.PropertyType.IsGenericType
    && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>)
    let entityType = p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First()
    where typeof(IncomingServiceOrderBase).IsAssignableFrom(entityType)
    select p.Name;
```

(this returns the names of the properties; if you want the actual DbSet instances, replace `p.Name` with `p.GetValue(context, null)`)

Answer (score 2):

`typeof(BaseType).IsAssignableFrom(DerivedType)`.  It'll return true/false.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx

To turn `DbSet<T>` into `T` (so you can do this comparison) take each property's type and do something like this:

```
    public static Type GetGenericBaseType( this Type Type ) {
        if ( Type == null ) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "Type" );
        }
        if ( !Type.IsGenericType ) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( "Type", Type.FullName + " isn't Generic" );
        }
        Type[] args = Type.GetGenericArguments();
        if ( args.Length != 1 ) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( "Type", Type.FullName + " isn't a Generic type with one argument -- e.g. T<U>" );
        }
        return args[0];
    }
```